# query to show both joins

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I am trying to build a query to output `Comments`, `Comment_Date`, `Username` or `First_Name` depending if a `UserID` or `StaffID` is pressent in the table row.

I can work it with just `UserID` or `StaffID` but when I add the both joins it displays nothing.

So Once again I need to output `Comments`, `Comment_Date`, `Username` and `First_Name`. 
Any help is appreciated.

**My query**

```
 select('Report_Comments.Comments, Report_Comments.Comment_Date, Login.Username, staff.First_Name')
        ->from('Report_Comments')
        ->join('Login staff', 'Report_Comments.UserID = Login.LoginID')
        ->join('staff', 'Report_Comments.UserID_Staff = staff.StaffID');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find out from the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) (search for "join"), the call to `join()` has two required arguments. The first one is the joined **table**, the second one is the join **condition**. Apparently you squeezed two tables and two join conditions into its arguments and this is why the query generated by CodeIgniter has errors.

Your code should read:

```
select('Report_Comments.Comments, Report_Comments.Comment_Date, Login.Username,
    staff.First_Name')
->from('Report_Comments')
->join('Login', 'Report_Comments.UserID = Login.LoginID')
->join('staff', 'Report_Comments.UserID_Staff = staff.StaffID')
->where('reportID', '53');
```

Comment: Hmm it dose not get the data though this way, If i just have one join it works, but with both it dose not retrieve data. but it seems like its correct. il have a play.

Comment: It works if I remove either join, but they dont work together

Answer (score 1):

`Report_Comments` JOIN `Login` `staff` ON `Report_Comments`.`UserID` =
`Login`.`LoginID, Report_Comments`.`UserID_Staff`

There are missing `join` keywords in the above. If you wish to `join` tables, all of them have to be `join`ed with the explicit conditions.

Correct it to:

```
SELECT `Report_Comments`.`Comments`, `Report_Comments`.`Comment_Date`, `Login`.`Username`, `staff`.`First_Name`
FROM `Report_Comments`
JOIN `Login` ON `Report_Comments`.`UserID` = `Login`.`LoginID
JOIN `staff` ON `Report_Comments`.`UserID_Staff = `staff`.`StaffID` 
WHERE `ReportID` = '53'
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for quick reply. il read this, try it and let you know +1 for back ticks

Comment: The backticks on the join conditions don't match.

Comment: Not working, but going to try again. when i get it working ill accept